# What is the default username and password for Arch Linux

Tags: linux, archlinux, archlinux-arm

I have installed the Arch Linux and loaded it using VM then tried to login with root/root and it says login incorrect, could you let me know the default Arch linux username and password

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is no default user for the os. You can try root without any password and it most probably will prompt you to create a user.

It might be that your VM created a user for you. Search the docs for the VM.

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.